# Cross Domain Ajax request - youtube

Tags: jquery, ajax, request

I want to call client side ajax request with cross domain for following URL:

http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=IZ-_3Ug3wqU

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://youtube.com/get_video_info",
    data: { video_id: "IZ-_3Ug3wqU" },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (response) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert('error');
    },
    complete: function () {
        alert('complete');
    }
});
```

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Please check question now i have add code for request

Comment: Your request seems correct, however the url is returning a `301 Moved Permanently` status code.

Comment: Yeah i tried many way but not working... if you get any solution than please let me know..because its too important for me..

Answer (score 1):

I believe the proper way to access this data is through the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) created specifically for this purpose.

The request would looks something like the following:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=YOUR_API_KEY
 &part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status
```

Comment: I want to get all details of video like thumbnil image, title, all available video format and video size and also download link for all video format

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the request is OK.

Have you allowed CORS by adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

If you didn't, in .htaccess, add

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>   
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://youtube.com"
</IfModule>
```

EDIT:

The only "good practices" way I can think to do this is using the header, you can check http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html and see if any of this configurations work.

Other way may be using the YoutubeAPI from your server to access directly this information that way, and then calling this script with the ajax call (the script working as a "bridge").

Comment: Yes its PHP code but i am working on asp.net. And i also tried to set in web.config but its also not working

Comment: problem is he won't have access to youtube's server to set the header

Comment: Yes youtube does not allow request for user domain

Comment: youtube API is second option but they does not return all video format URL (flv,mp4,3gp etc) for download video.